# How to convert xml to schematron

Tags: xml, xslt, soa, schematron, oracle-soa

Can anyone please explain me how to convert the xml file to schematron file for validation? I am working on oracle soa and I wasn't able to figure out how.

Comment: Converting an XML file to schematron is rather like taking a video of a cricket match as input and producing the rules of cricket as output. I'm not aware of any tool that does it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an XSD to SCH (Schematron) if you want in [here](https://code.google.com/p/schematron/downloads/detail?name=XSD2SCH-2010-03-11.zip) if that what you are asking for!

PS: This is an ANT script